# Put html table tag to Jasper Report

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I have a parameter input to Text Field with html markup language. But when I put tag `<table>`, It doesn't show at all.

Is there any way to show table from that html tag ?
If it can not, is there any alternative solution ?